# Converting \x00 with a space

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-2.x, spaces

Im reading a /proc//cmdline file via:

```
pfile = '/proc/%s/cmdline' % pid
if os.path.isfile(pfile):
    fh = open(pfile, 'r')
    pname = repr(fh.read())
    fh.close()

print pname
```

OUTPUT:

```
'myexe\x00arg\x00arg2'
```

if i remove repr, there is no space between the words

```
'myexeargarg2'
```

So i changed it to

```
' '.join(fh.read().split('\x00'))
```

Then, I got:

```
'myexe arg arg2'
```

Just wondering if  there are other ways to convert \x00 into a space?

Comment: `str.replace('\x00'.' ')`?

Comment: Maybe something [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/510399-byte-to-hex-and-hex-to-byte-string-conversion/) would help

Comment: `str.replace('\x00', ' ')` (@RNar's answer has a typo)

Comment: @ValentinLorentz wow didn't even realize, awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a short example that will help you to answer your Question.

```
content = b'cmd\x00arg1\x00arg2\x00'
print(content.replace("\x00", " "))
```

It will replace the occurences as explain [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#bytes.replace).

Comment: Not working in python3 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up an ASCII table you will see that `\x00` is the NULL character. When you print something `str` is called on it which attempts to create a *printable* version of the data and unprintable characters don't get printed. You can see which characters are printable by looking at [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.printable):

```
import string
if '\x00' in string.printable:
    print "printable"
else:
    print "unprintable"
```

When you [run this](https://ideone.com/hmOezC) you will see this outputs "unprintable".

However `repr` makes an attempt to generate something that can recreate the original data so the `\x00` needs to be visible there because that's needed to recreate the original data.

If you want to get spaces wherever you had `\x00` all you need to do is to [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) it with a space with `fh.replace('\x00', ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

For python3 needs the "b" binary prefix for replace.

```
content = b'cmd\x00arg1\x00arg2\x00'
print(content.replace(b"\x00", b" "))
```

Result:
b'cmd arg1 arg2 '